# Short keys to make a line comment in shell script Emacs?

Tags: shortcut-keys, scripts, emacs

I want to write shell scripts by using Emacs. I have already known to turn shell-script-mode on, but still don't know which short keys to make a line become comment. For example, which short keys in Emacs should I use to make line:

```
cat /dev/null > messages
```

become

```
# cat /dev/null > messages
```

Obviously , I can directly type '#' at the beginning of that line, but that's inconvenient for block of lines. Thanks.

Comment: Check out [emacs.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`comment-dwim` command is usually bound to <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>;</kbd> (`M-;` using emacs notation). Just mark the lines you want to comment before pressing. The way Emacs will comment the line depends on the current major mode.

If you want to know more about commenting code, you can read [this article](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Comment-Commands.html) from the official documentation.